# JSON pretty format only of part of a file in vim

Tags: json, vim

In VIm, is there a way to print a JSON snipped inside a file in the "pretty" format?

For example, having the following file

```
# a comment
def my_func():
    pass

{"bla": [1, 2, 3], "yes": false}  # <--- pretty print this

# another comment
<foo>why do I mix everything in one file?</foo>
<bar>it's an example, dude</bar>
```

I would like to change the marked line to

```
{
   "bla":[
      1,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "yes":false
}
```

I'm looking for something like `:%!python -m json.tool` but only for the selected lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specifying the line number should work. For example:

```
:5!python -m json.tool
```

Or if it takes multiple lines:

```
:4,6!python -m json.tool
```

Comment: obviously.. argh. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use visual mode to select the lines, and then it will auto fill the range when you type `:`

Comment: So people know - no need to pip install anything for this work as it relies on Python built-in json library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool

Answer (score 0):

A regex-based solution is:

`:%s/\({\)\|\(\[\)\|\(,\)\|\(\]\)\|\(}\)/\1\2\3\r\4\5/g`

followed by: `=gg`

**outputs:**

```
{
   "bla": [
      1,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "yes": false
}
```